# Opening an applet from a frame button click

Tags: java, applet

I have a button inside an frame. On the click of the button, applet should load in another frame. These exceptions are coming up. defg is my applet class. Is there some other way to do it. Thanks.

```
     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     JApplet applet = new defg();

     // Send the applet an init() message.
     applet.init();

     // Construct a JFrame.
     final JFrame frame =
             new JFrame("FrameTitle");

     // Transfer the applet's context pane to the JFrame.
     frame.setContentPane(applet.getContentPane());

     // Transfer the applet's menu bar into the JFrame.
     // This line can be omitted if the applet
     // does not create a menu bar.
     frame.setJMenuBar(applet.getJMenuBar());

     // Make the application shut down when the user clicks
     // on the close button.
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

     // Set the size of the frame.
     // To pack the frame as tightly as possible
     // replace the setSize() message with the following.
     // frame.pack();
     frame.setSize(800, 800);

     // Set the location of the frame.
     frame.setLocation(30, 30);

     // Show the frame.
     frame.setVisible(true);



}
```

The exception...

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at defg.init(defg.java:198)
at AppMain1.jButton1ActionPerformed(AppMain1.java:80)
at AppMain1.access$0(AppMain1.java:75)
at AppMain1$1.actionPerformed(AppMain1.java:40)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Is there more to that stack trace?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sorry. Added now

Comment: The problem seems to be in `defg.init(defg.java:190)`, what's in the `init` method of your `defg` applet?

Comment: try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    initComponents();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: There's your problem.  Consider using `invokeLater` instead of `invokeAndWait`.  Having said that, that could break the expectations of the API.  You might need to initialise the applet on a separate thread.  Maybe a `SwingWorker`

Comment: Changed it . Getting new exceptions. Updated them. Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is within you applet's init method...

```
try { 
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
            initComponents(); 
        } 
    }); 
} catch (Exception ex) { 
    ex.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

You can't call `invokeAndWait` from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread as this would generate a deadlock

Instead, you want to call `init` from outside the Event Dispatching Thread and then, when loaded, load the rest of the UI.

In this case, a `SwingWorker` might be useful, for example...

```
public class LoadAppletWorker extends SwingWorker<JApplet, JApplet> {

    @Override
    protected JApplet doInBackground() throws Exception {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        JApplet applet = new defg();

        // Send the applet an init() message.
        applet.init();

        return applet;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            JApplet applet = get();

            // Construct a JFrame.
            final JFrame frame
                    = new JFrame("FrameTitle");

            // Transfer the applet's context pane to the JFrame.
            frame.setContentPane(applet.getContentPane());

            // Transfer the applet's menu bar into the JFrame.
            // This line can be omitted if the applet
            // does not create a menu bar.
            frame.setJMenuBar(applet.getJMenuBar());

            // Make the application shut down when the user clicks
            // on the close button.
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            // Set the size of the frame.
            // To pack the frame as tightly as possible
            // replace the setSize() message with the following.
            // frame.pack();
            frame.setSize(800, 800);

            // Set the location of the frame.
            frame.setLocation(30, 30);

            // Show the frame.
            frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Initapp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Then you would call it using something like...

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    new LoadAppletWorker().execute();

}
```

Comment: Just beware, I think there are other things you need to do to load an applet this way, but I'm not 100% sure what they all are (the applet context is one of them I think)